# Why would Silverlight be crashing in Release but not in Debug mode?

Tags: silverlight, crash, release-mode, debug-mode

I have a Silverlight App that has worked well in **Debug** and **Release** modes for weeks.

It still works well in **Debug** mode.

However, now when I run it in **Release** mode, it starts, shows me the screen, loads the data, then **hangs**, and the browser (Firefox) **closes automatically**. I've tried other browsers and each of them crashes, Chrome says "**The Silverlight Plug-In has crashed**" for instance.

Here are the last lines of **Output** that I get:

```
'firefox.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.Windows.Controls'
'firefox.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit'
'firefox.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50524.0\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'
'firefox.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50524.0\en-US\System.Windows.debug.resources.dll'
The program '[1120] firefox.exe: Silverlight' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

**How can I get more information about what is happening at the point of crash in Release mode that is not happening in Debug mode?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://asdev.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E838B9D306E3255E!301.entry) seems relevant to your issue. From the update at the bottom, it seems that

> the display string used for the
>   debugger triggered a program path
>   which was not executed otherwise, and
>   there it entered in an endless loop

Comment: thanks, that allowed me to put a breakpoint at the right spot and see what it was doing, which led to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031869/how-to-handle-not-enough-isolatedstorage-issue-deep-in-data-loader

Comment: Both the SO link in comments and the link in the answer are both dead, Can anyone add more info to this answer?